# Accessing DOM element in WKwebView

Tags: ios, swift2, wkwebview

In swift 2.1, Xcode7.1.1

My code loads a local index.html into a WKwebView. How can I have a reference to the textFields so that I can set some of their properties? like `myWebViewTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false` or `myWebViewTextField.enabled = false`

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebScriptObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WebScriptObject) says:

> You get a window WebScriptObject object by sending windowScriptObject to your WebView object.

I am not sure how to go from here. Thank

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView! = nil  //allows the class to refrence WKWebView
var webView: WKWebView?

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    self.webView = WKWebView()
    self.view = self.webView!
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //path explained http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/fileurl.html
    let baseUrl = NSURL(string: "file:///<path>/")
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html")
    let HTMLString: NSString?

    do {
        HTMLString = try NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        webView!.loadHTMLString(HTMLString as! String, baseURL: baseUrl )

    } catch {
        HTMLString = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading the wrong class' docs. WebView and WKWebView are not the same. The latter is faster and more secure but not as manipulable.

For WKWebView, you'd want to use [wkwebview.evaluateJavaScript](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:) to send a whole string of code that does the manipulations to the DOM. The completionHandler can *asynchronously* receive simple results like strings and numbers and fire off more JS evaluations based on those, but you can't receive DOM element references and directly tweak their properties from Swift.

Comment: Thanks for that, I need to set 'myWebViewTextField.userInteractionEnabled = false' so that the iOS keyboard gets disabled, can I do that via wkwebview.evaluateJavaScript? I will update the question. :)

Comment: You can't get at the underlying UIKit element that WebKit may-or-not be using - that other answer was literally about a UITextField, which your <text> element is not.

Comment: You could use send a javascript command like `textBox.hidden = !textBox.hidden` to the webview to toggle the the text elements visibility. or use .blur() to remove focus. But you cannot bypass the iOS keyboard in a WKWebView if you use normal HTML text elements to accept input.

Comment: There is a private header for the _WKInputDelegate protocol (wkwebview._formDelegate) that has a method `func _webView(webView: WKWebView, focusShouldStartInputSession`) that can allow you to suppress the keyboard. https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/833ed3dae1ec62fcb9a4c5dbb42bfba94c55f61a/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/_WKInputDelegate.h#L45

Comment: As 2022 the link is dead.